# Употребление местоимений в предложениях

Tags: местоимения

1. Почему недопустим вариант написания: "В доме раздавались крики. Они пытались выломать раму."?
2. Допустим ли вариант написания и почему: "Алексей читал книгу, и вдруг в переломный момент вспыхнули эмоции, завладев им." ?

Спасибо за ответ. Если нетрудно, не могли бы дать статью про подобные случаи употребления местоимений, чтобы не допускать ошибок? (А то не понимаю, почему в предложении нельзя использовать местоимения "его, им, него..."

Comment: В первом случае не ясно к чему относится местоимение, нет согласованности с предыдущим предложением, выходи что Они - Крики пытались выломать раму, кто Они не ясно. Во втором, как по мне, так всё "завладев им" - лишнее, так как плеоназм вспыхнули-завладев. либо вообще убрать либо поменять на " .. в переломный момент им завладели вспыхнувшие эмоции" - тогда ни проблем с согласованием, ни тяжеловесности.

Comment: А еще лучше, убрать нафиг терминологию, вроде "эмоции" и "переломный момент" и описать эти эмоции: "и вдруг, от самого основания головы, по спине, плечам и даже до кончиков пальцев его рук побежали мурашки". Латинизмы "момент", "эмоции" нужно использовать очень осторожно, потому что чаще всего это термины и хоть сколько к ним не прибавь эпитетов они терминами быть не перестанут и смысла фразе это не прибавит.

Comment: Термины нужны для обозначение результата действия чего-то, или результата анализа чего-то, использование их не в научном тексте, а в повествовании, может нафиг убить это повествование. Зачем рассказывать, если и так понятно "Книгу читал и в переломный момент испытал эмоции" - банальщина, не ясно зачем такое вообще рассказывать. Если бы книгу жёг, ел, и испытал эмоции в когда читал предисловие - то еще куда ни шло, а тут прям бессодержательность.